# Need help averaging a nested DAX function

Tags: dax

Need is to find the top 6 of production "values" between operators("op"). Secondly to average them across each op. I need help with the DAX code.

I tried creating a separate table using topN to find top values. Then used AverageX, CurrentGroup and GroupBy. The error is that GroupBy statement must find the average across CurrentGroup, must refer to CurrentGroup or a constant.

```html
Table = 
GROUPBY (
    GROUPBY (
        fat,
        'fat'[op],
               "topn", TOPN( 6, fat, fat[Value],DESC)
    ),
    'fat'[op],
    "mn",SUMX( CURRENTGROUP (), [topn] )
)
```

This is easier done in R:

```html
  dt<-read.table("data2.csv", TRUE) 
  library(plyr)
  n=6 #or other
  df1<-ddply(dt,~name,summarise,mean=mean(tail(sort(val),n)))
```

:[A sample of the input and expected output is linked:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCEt3.png)

Comment: Can you give some sample data and desired output?

Comment: You sample image is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to take the top `6` values for each `op` and average those to get a single row.

If that's correct, then I'd suggest something like this:

```
AvgTop6 = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    fat[op],
    "Mean",
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE(fat[Value]),
        FILTER(fat, RANK.EQ(fat[Value], fat[Value]) <= 6)
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, you understood the problem well. But, that script didn't work saying that it can not refer to multiple columns, which in turn can not be converted to a scalar. Also, I did attach a link to the sample input and expected output. Thaks.

Comment: It's a table formula. If you're getting a cannot be converted to scalar error, then that means you are trying to use it as a measure or calculated column instead of as a formula for a new table. If you want a measure that returns a scalar, all you need is the `CALCULATE` part.